# Getting a document notarized in Iceland without visiting embassy

Tags: new-york-state, notaries, iceland

My wife and I have agreed to a divorce. We live in New York State. The document is completed, and ready to be signed. But it must be notarized and my wife is in Iceland.

The normal solution for this is to visit the US embassy. However, she is in the countryside and has a broken leg, so it is difficult for her to travel. The embassy only does notarial appointments two times a month and they are not on days my wife will be in Reykjavik.

Can an Icelandic notary do this service for her?

There is an app: https://www.notarize.com. Can this or some other app be used for this purpose?

Is there any other solution that could work here?

Comment: FWIW, Iceland is just not that big (geographically, or in population which is comparable to three blocks in Manhattan), and getting around with a broken leg isn't that hard. They do have accessible vans there. Also, since it is a small country, and there are only about 1005 Americans in all of Iceland, the embassy might be willing to be flexible and send someone out to visit her. I would not trust the app.